# Unity - New Input System - Player Animation Triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a simple player action, such as a roll, that prevents the player from spamming the roll. Currently I have everything working, including the switch of animations via trigger, but the player is able to spam Shift (key for roll) and get an infinite speed boost.

This is my first game, and first go at Unity/C# in general, so **any/all constructive criticism is always appreciated**. This was my attempt at a simple system:

```
 private void OnMovement(InputValue value)
        {
            Vector2 inputMovement = value.Get<Vector2>();
            _inputDirection = new Vector3(inputMovement.x, 0f, inputMovement.y);
        }

 private void OnRoll(InputValue value)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RollThePlayer());
        }

 public IEnumerator RollThePlayer()
    {
        if (canRoll)
        {
            PlayerAnimator.SetTrigger("Roll");

            IsRolling = true;
            canRoll = false;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(RollDuration);

            IsRolling = false;
            canRoll = true;
        }
    }

 private void MoveThePlayer()
    {
        switch (_currentInput)
        {
            case true:
                _movement.Set(_smoothDirection.x, 0f, _smoothDirection.z);
                _movement = _movement.normalized * MovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

                if (IsRolling && !canRoll)
                {
                    _movement = _movement * RollSpeed;
                }

                else
                {
                    PlayerAnimator.SetBool("Idling", false);
                    PlayerAnimator.SetBool("Running", true);
                }

                PlayerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + _movement);
                break;

            case false:
                IdleThePlayer();
                break;
        }
    }
```